# First order non-homogenous differential equation - issue

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation

$F'(\tau)=[1-F(\tau)]p(z)$, with $F'(\tau)\equiv \frac{\partial F}{\partial \tau}$

and the book says to use the following boundary condition $F(0)=0$.

$\tau$ denotes time, and since $p(z)$ does not change over time I consider it as a constant.

I easily solve the homogenous equivalent of the complete equation:

$F_c(\tau)=Ae^{-p(z)\tau}$

Where $A \equiv e^{F(0)}$ and since $F(0)=0$, then $A=1$, and the previous equation reads as

$F_c(\tau)=e^{-p(z)\tau}$

Then considering the easiest particular solution of the complete equation, i.e., $F'(\tau)=0$, I get

$F_p(\tau)=1$

Then, the solution of the differential equation reads as

$F(\tau)=F_p(\tau)+F_c(\tau)=1+ e^{-p(z)\tau}$

However, the book's result is $F(\tau)=1 - e^{-p(z)\tau}$

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forced the boundary condition on the solution to the homogenous equation, not the actual solution. Note that your solution satisfies $F(0) = 2$. You had to "carry" the constant $A$ and determine it only when you had the solution to the original equation, that is,
$$F(\tau)=F_p(\tau)+F_c(\tau)=1+ Ae^{-p(z)\tau}$$
and you'd find that $A = -1$.

Comment: As an additional note: this method of finding the solution to the homogenous equation is: a GENERAL solution to the homogenous plus a PARTICULAR solution to the non-homogenous. will give a GENERAL solution to the non-homogenous. Since you forced the boundary condition on the homogenous one, you used a particular solution for both, so you got a particular solution to the non-homogenous that satisfies a different boundary condition (namely, $F(0) = 2$)

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{F'}{1-F}=p(z)\implies\ln (1-F(\tau))=-p(z)\tau\implies 1-F(\tau)=e^{-p(z)\tau}\implies F(\tau)=1-e^{-p(z)\tau}.$$ Your mistake was in calculating the constant $A$ for the homogeneus equation, in fact it must be done for the final solution you have to carry the constant to get $F(\tau)=1+Ae^{-p(z)\tau}$, and now evaluating at $0$ you will get that $A=-1$.